# How to extract sub-formulas(predicates, terms) in Z3 efficiently?

Tags: java, performance, z3

Suppose I want to extract all sub-formulas(predicates, terms) from a given constraint with  the type of BoolExpr and here are two examples:

```
(f(x)=2 and f(y)=3) or (f(z)=1 and f(y)=3)
The output should be f(x)=2, f(y)=3 and f(z)=1.

(p and q) or (p or r) and (p and (q or r))
The output should be p, q and r.
```

A naive way would be traversing the entire AST and recording all the unique sub-formulas. This is unpleasant when there are bunch of redundant nodes in the AST and we have to perform such extraction frequently.
I was wondering if there exists a clean and efficient way to do this.

I am using the Java API for Z3.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the fact that expressions are unique. 
You can insert them into ordered dictionaries or hash-tables and use the dictionaries/hash-tables
to detect whether you already traversed the same sub-expression.

You can also leverage the fact that each sub-expression has a unique identifier.
The identifier is unique as long as the expression is still "live", that is, it has not been garbage collected. You can of course "pinn" (ensure that expressions are not garbage collected) expressions by maintaining a list of expressions you track.
The unique identifier is accessed using the method "getId". It is defined in AST.java
(and Ast.cs for .NET, z3_api.h for C, and z++.h for C++).

```
  /**
   * A unique identifier for the AST (unique among all ASTs).
   **/
  public int getId() throws Z3Exception
  {
      return Native.getAstId(getContext().nCtx(), getNativeObject());
  }
```

A good traversal algorithm then maintains a cache (the dictionary from integer identifiers to the sub-formulas). Before traversing a sub-expression it checks the cache if this identifier is already seen.

The identifier is used for the "compareTo" method on AST objects that are used
for both expressions (function applications, quantifies, bound variables), sorts and functions. 
So you can also choose to maintain the cache as a just a set of previously seen expressions without resorting to accessing the lower-level integer identifier.
See AST.java for more details.

Comment: If I fully control the operations, say, conjunction, disjunction, etc. I can cache the unique sub-expression easily. The problem comes from the fact that I invoke "ctx-solver-simplify" frequently to reduce its size. During simplification, the number of unique sub-expressions can shrink and I have no choice but traverse the simplified expr to get the new unique sub-expressions again, which is quite inefficient.